# fastlane/supply dynamic what's new (changelogs)

Tags: android, metadata, fastlane

[fastlane supply android](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/supply#changelogs-whats-new) metadata has the following structure:

```
└── fastlane
    └── metadata
        └── android
            ├── en-US
            │   └── changelogs
            │       ├── 100000.txt
            │       └── 100100.txt
            └── fr-FR
                └── changelogs
                    └── 100100.txt
```

Production builds and versions is changed some times before release so I had to change files names in changelog directories after every build.

I want to have only one "what's new" (changelog) file per locale for the latest build. Something like whats_new.txt

Does fastlane or supply provide such a feature?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want it's supported nowadays with the `default.txt` file

https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/supply/#changelogs-whats-new

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*supply* is not set up to support such a strategy right now, sorry. I think it is a reasonable feature request though. Please submit an issue in our [GitHub repository](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane) if it's something you'd like to see be possible!

Answer (score 0):

A plugin like [`changelog`](https://github.com/pajapro/fastlane-plugin-changelog) might be what you are after. It allows you to pull from one changelog file like so:

```
read_changelog(
  changelog_path: './custom_folder/CHANGELOG.md',   # Specify path to CHANGELOG.md
  section_identifier: '[Unreleased]',   # Specify what section to read
  excluded_markdown_elements: '["###"]' # Specify which markdown elements should be excluded
)
```

I do not, however, see builtin support for a per-locale changelog. For reference, the [`release_notes.txt`](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/deliver#default-values) file and/or function provide the functionality you describe when using fastlane for iOS projects.

Comment: checkout this plugin: [fastlane-plugin-changelog](https://github.com/pajapro/fastlane-plugin-changelog)